# Flyway migration and hibernate context, execution order

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am using spring boot with default configuration with flyway and hibernate. I'm wondering about the execution order.
According to the documentation `Flyway checks the version of the database and applies new migrations automatically before the rest of the application starts.`

Where can I find a source code confirming that statement? Where execution order is determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot use a `FlywayMigrationInitializer` bean ( which implements `InitializingBean` with a high order ( **oder = 0** ) ), so that afterPropertiesSet which contains the flyway migration function :

```
@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    if (this.migrationStrategy != null) {
        this.migrationStrategy.migrate(this.flyway);
    }
    else {
        this.flyway.migrate();
    }
}
```

will execute the logic inside `Flyway.java#migrate()` which

> Starts the database migration. All pending migrations will be applied
>   in order.Calling migrate on an up-to-date database has no effect.

You can refer to the [Flyway.java](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc.html) of javadoc  and [FlywayMigrationInitializer.java](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayMigrationInitializer.html) javadoc

Comment: so for example hibernate context, does not have the order set?

Comment: the definiton of  `sessionFactory` bean will `dependsOn` the definition of Flyway bean, you can see this [example from flyway doc](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/#spring-configuration)